# RabbitMQ in Action:queue in cluster

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

> Not to worry: you can have your consumers reconnect to the cluster and
>   recreate the queues, right? Only if the queues weren’t originally
>   marked durable. If the queues being re-created were marked as durable,
>   redeclaring them from another node will get  you  an  ugly  404 
>   NOT_FOUND  error.  **This  ensures  messages  in  that  queue  on  the
>   failed node don’t disappear when you restore it to the cluster.** The
>   only way to get that specific queue name back into the cluster is to
>   actually restore the failed node. But if the queues your consumers try
>   to re-create are not durable, the redeclarations will suc- ceed and
>   you’re ready to rebind them and keep trucking.

In  the author says that durable queue cannot be redeclared for eusuring data not lossing , How to comprehend this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on where RabbitMQ keeps the published messages. If you declare a queue in node A then the queue messages will live in that node. What is replicated is the queue metadata, that is the queue properties, but not the messages. So if node A dies, then in that node you have the messages that were published to that queue.

So let's say now you go to node B and re declare that queue, durable as well, like it was in node A. If that procedure was allowed then you would lose all the messages from node B simply because the broker would think the queue lived in node B.

Comment: Thank you! I will do some test for this